# import py file into script running in scripting workspace

Tags: python, scripting

While making a new script I need to import modules from another script

I am developing the script inside Blenders "scripting workspace"

```
from sys import path
path.append(bpy.path.abspath("//")+'K://path/to the folder/that/has-the-script')
from Script import add_plane_mesh
```

Ends up in error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Script'

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to append the abspath of the current blend file to the full path of the script folder.

Try this instead:   (Note the use of 'r' as prefix to the path, so that the backslash characters are not treated as string escapes.)

```
import bpy
from sys import path
path.append(r'K:\path\to the folder\that\has-the-script')
from Script import add_plane_mesh
```

Comment: Seems to be working.... Now need to learn how to execute the script I imported. Thanks for the help.. 

Just for me to know. 
I have a script (lets call it script1) that runs on its own. When running it places a cube in the model.
The script I import is "script1"

Is it possible when running the new script to "execute" script1 and draw the cube?

Comment: The cleanest way to do this would be to put the script's code inside a function, and then call the function when you want to draw the cube.

Comment: Thanks Marty for helping me out!! Appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome.  Enjoy Blender Python programming.

Comment: Thanks Marty. you 2